# Is there any chance to retrieve files after deleting from HDFS trash

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, recycle-bin

In our project we have four environments such has Production, Development, UAT and QA. I am using the UAT environment.

We have a cluster with 43 Data Nodes. My role is HDFS clean up. Unfortunately I deleted some jobs from Hive database and also from trash. Is there any chance to retrieve those files and tables?

I am using fallowing commands:

```
hadoop fs -du -h / | grep ' T'
hadoop fs -rm -r source path
hadoop fs -rm -r .Trash/some path
```

Comment: Normally deleting file from trash is permanent. You can not recover it. But the only way to recover is to use some forensic tools. Like disk recovery tools. The recovery tools will only recover if the memory is not overwritten.

Comment: Trash should be emptied using -expunge command. Probably files are not deleted by using -rm -r command.